# Why does my android application crash when starting a new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, httpurlconnection

My app keeps crashing as I try to start a new activity (uploadLocation.class).
No errors are highlighted and I can't debug within the uploadLocation class.

I have added permissions to my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

MainActivity

As this section of code from the MainActivity is executed the application crashes.

```
public void uploadMyLocation (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, uploadLocation.class));
}
```

Other than the this class works as it should (complete MainActivity.java below)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

Button uploadButton;
TextView latitudeView, longitudeView, networkView;
Location lastKnownLocation;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
String latString1, lonString1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    networkView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkView);

    latitudeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitudeView);
    longitudeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitudeView);

    buildGoogleApiClient();

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        networkView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        uploadButton.setEnabled(false);
    }


}

public void uploadMyLocation (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, uploadLocation.class));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(100); // location updated every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    lastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

    if(lastKnownLocation != null){
        latString1 = String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
        lonString1 = String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
    }
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latString1 = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    lonString1 = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    updateUI();
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

void updateUI(){
    latitudeView.setText(latString1);
    longitudeView.setText(lonString1);
}
}
```

uploadLocation

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class uploadLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView myLatitudeView, myLongitudeView, latitudeView, longitudeView;
String latString, lonString;

public void uploadInfo(View view){
    latString = latitudeView.getText().toString();
    lonString = longitudeView.getText().toString();
    myLatitudeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLatitudeView);
    myLongitudeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLongitudeView);
    myLatitudeView.setText(latString);
    myLongitudeView.setText(lonString);
    BackgroundOp backgroundOp = new BackgroundOp();
    backgroundOp.execute(latString, lonString);
    finish();
}

class BackgroundOp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    String myUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myUrl = "http://[web address]/[php script]";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        String latString, lonString;
        latString = data [0];
        lonString = data [1];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String myDataStream = URLEncoder.encode("Latitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(latString, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("Longitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lonString, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(myDataStream);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Upload Successful";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

XML file

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload Location"
    android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/networkView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="uploadInfo" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Data"
    android:id="@+id/getDataButton"
    android:onClick="uploadMyLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[Latitude]"
    android:id="@+id/latitudeView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/uploadButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[Longitude]"
    android:id="@+id/longitudeView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/latitudeView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/uploadButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[My Latitude]"
    android:id="@+id/myLatitudeView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getDataButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/getDataButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[My Longitude]"
    android:id="@+id/myLongitudeView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getDataButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/getDataButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="[Network Unavailable]"
    android:id="@+id/networkView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="169dp" />
```

Compiler log:

```
   03-24 16:11:26.893 17436-17436/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-24 16:11:27.044 17436-17467/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
03-24 16:11:27.058 17436-17467/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
03-24 16:11:27.059 17436-17467/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
03-24 16:11:27.155 17436-17475/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-24 16:11:27.160 17436-17436/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-24 16:11:27.208 17436-17475/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 40d, I21dda
                                                                        Build Date                       : 08/24/15
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25
                                                                        Local Branch                     : 
                                                                        Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.4.1.1_r9
                                                                        Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
03-24 16:11:27.216 17436-17475/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-24 16:11:27.225 17436-17475/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-24 16:11:27.388 17436-17436/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3563b026 time:407225888
03-24 16:11:45.883 17436-17436/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-24 16:11:45.902 17436-17436/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp, PID: 17436
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method uploadInfo(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'uploadButton'
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4861)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19980)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
03-24 16:12:19.041 17436-17436/com.cityuni.sophie.locationapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17436 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You must get Crash report please share this.

Comment: You probably have a NULL somewhere.  I know that sounds like a simple explanation.  But many times when you go to open a new activity, it's dependent on something passed in.  If that something isn't there, it crashes.  And you won't see anything about it in the code editor.  Check your logs.

Comment: OK Finally I figured out your error, See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kindly inform you Every Activity needs to override [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method as per doc

> This method is Called when the activity is starting. This is where most initialization should go: calling `setContentView(int)` to inflate the activity's UI, using `findViewById(int)` to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI

I suggest you to override necessary methods And also don't forget to call `super.onCreate()` inside `onCreate()` method.

**UPDATE :**

I figured out your error, That is because of this attribute

```
android:onClick="uploadInfo"
```

Because `XML` you provided is `activity_main.xml`. And you are making the method `uploadInfo` in another Activity. So I suggest you either remove this attribute OR create `uploadInfo` method in `MainActivity` not inside `uploadLocation` Activity.

To get hints you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on that attribute and create method uploadInfo as Android Studio suggests you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added your new activity to the android manifest file.
Try adding this.

```
<activity android:name=".uploadLocation">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the compiler log and added it, re-running it still crashes

Answer (score -1):

When I've start the development on Android I've meet the same problem and i use this for fix my app crash :

Try extends Activity instead of extends AppCompatActivity.

If don't work maybe you have an Component null, check you instanciate all component declared in your XML.

Comment: The issue here has nothing to do with Activity vs AppCompatActivity.  That would only be an issue if the OP was not using an AppCompat based theme.  The real issue here is the fact that there's no onCreate in uploadInfo, and it has a non-default constructor.  IN addition, the way that the onClick attribute is specified, it will not find a method to execute.